# Jquery applying -webkit-animation style instead of -webkit-animation-duration style in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, safari

When I try to change the -webkit-animation-duration style via jQuery 2.1.3 in Chrome, it applies the -webkit-animation style instead, essentially overriding all animations that have been applied previously via css stylesheets.

It works perfectly in Chrome and in Firefox (using non-prefixed styles).

Here is an [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qEYXJM).

The only workaround I have found is to set the style via .attr, but this overrides my existing inline styles, and doing a search and replace would be too intensive for the rate at which I am updating this.

Here is the jQuery code:

```
$('.mask').css("-webkit-animation-duration", "50s");
$('.filler').css("-webkit-animation-duration", "50s");
$('.spinner').css("-webkit-animation-duration", "50s");
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I have confirmed that the same thing happens when using javascript to apply the style. It is updated to use pure JS in the example, but here is the code in case someone updates it:

```
document.getElementById("pie1").style['-webkit-animation-duration'] = "50s";
document.getElementById("pie2").style['-webkit-animation-duration'] = "50s";
document.getElementById("pie3").style['-webkit-animation-duration'] = "50s";
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out what was going on. Safari combines all animation css properties into one of the shorthand properties. The solution was to pass through the rest of the animation parameters (which were luckily static) when making changes via jQuery. This seems like a silly thing for Safari to do since it would override any other animation parameters.